Asymptotic estimate of the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-\xi^{2q}}$
In V. Yu. Krylov's paper [1], he estimates the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-\xi^{2q}}$ using harmonic measure arguments (which I don't understand since the reference is written in Russian language).
Then, he got, there exist some $C>0$ such that, for large enough $y$ and any $q\in \mathbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$, the following inequality holds true
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\xi^{2q}} e^{iy\xi} d\xi\right| \leq 
\exp(-Cy).
$$
I have two questions:

How to prove this inequality?
Is there some kind of analogy to this inequality in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

P.S. The English edition, to which the reference refers, skipped the chapter that I needed.
Reference
[1] V. Yu. Krylov, "Some properties of the distribution corresponding to the equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = (-1)^{q}\frac{\partial^{2q} u}{\partial x^{2q}}$", (English. Russian original), Soviet Mathematics Doklady 1, 760-763 (1960); translation from Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR 132, 1254-1257 (1960), MR118953, Zbl 0095.32703.
